# Set font family for comments

Tags: fonts, comment, characters

In coq mode I have ligatures being used: instead of "fun", it shows λ in the programming code. But in the comments lambda transformed into a character I can't even copy, so I'll attach a screenshot:

[image: nt]

Something is wrong with the glyph. What font should I set to get lambda everywhere?

Comment: I had a look at `coq-mode`.  It just uses `font-lock-mode` with [syntactic highlighting](https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG/blob/d53ded580e30d49e7a783280fd9ba96bc9c1c39c/coq/coq-mode.el#L124-L126) and [`pretttify-symbols-mode`](https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG/blob/d53ded580e30d49e7a783280fd9ba96bc9c1c39c/coq/coq-mode.el#L251-L253). The face you are looking for should be `font-lock-comment-face`. Maybe, it is customized.

Comment: That looks more like a different character than a different font to me. You can check by putting your cursor on it and running `C-u C-x =` to show all the details about it. It'll tell you the name of the character as well as what font it used to draw it.

Comment: @db48x It is the same character lambda.

Comment: Sounds like the fonts used must be different.

Comment: @db48x After using a different font - "Monoid", it started to work. But why is lambda correct in the code and incorrect in comments?